# how to remove android edit text focus when it is disabled?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

In small devices soft keyboard's **"NEXT**" button is used to enter the value for edit texts without touching the edit text.

This is very helpful when multiple entry is to be filled..

But  i disabled  two edit text in between so i can't go beyond that edit text. the next key hides...

i used

`android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"`

for those two edit texts but no luck...

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to set them to be non-focusable?

## Programmatically (ie when you're deactivating the EditTexts):

```
yourEditText.setFocusable( false );
yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode( false );
```

## XML

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Hope this works out for you.